# I don't know where my error is at 'incorrect syntax near the keyword CONSTRAINT'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE ClassRegistration(
StudentID int   NOT NULL,
CourseID int    NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_ClassRegistration PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, CourseID),
CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Students,
FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Students(ID),
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Classes,
FOREIGN KEY(CourseID) REFERENCES Course(ClassNumber),
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

I believe it is simply an issue of where to put commas but I'm teaching myself and so it's hard to figure this out.

Comment: I`ve seen the same comma issue before,do you work from a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

The constraint definition does not have "embedded" commas:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassRegistration
(
   StudentID int   NOT NULL,
   CourseID int    NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT PK_ClassRegistration PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, CourseID),

   CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Students   --- no comma here
   FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Students(ID) -- no comma here
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

   CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Classes -- no comma here
   FOREIGN KEY(CourseID) REFERENCES Course(ClassNumber) -- no comma here
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Btw: the part `CONSTRAINT PK_ClassRegistration` is useless. You can't give the primary key constraint a name in MySQL (you can *specify* it, but it is ignored and always named `PRIMARY`)

Answer (score 1):

You add way too much comma,

```
CREATE TABLE ClassRegistration(
StudentID int   NOT NULL,
CourseID int    NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_ClassRegistration PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, CourseID),
CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Students
FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Students(ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Classes
FOREIGN KEY(CourseID) REFERENCES Course(ClassNumber)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

See this for information on correct syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE ClassRegistration(
    StudentID int   NOT NULL,
    CourseID int    NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, CourseID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Classes
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Students(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    CONSTRAINT FK_ClassRegistration_Classes
    FOREIGN KEY(CourseID) REFERENCES Course(ClassNumber) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```